# Android: How to uncheck checkbox without perform click on it?

Tags: android, checkbox

I have 3 checkbox in my Layout:

- (case #1) mCheckBoxAll: when is checked or unchecked, all other boxes are set in the same state.
- (case #2) mCheckBoxChoice1 and mCheckBoxChoice2: if one of these is unchecked by the user then the mCheckBoxAll must be unchecked.

  ```
  mCheckBoxAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
              @Override
              public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                  mCheckBoxChoice1.setChecked(isChecked);
                  mCheckBoxChoice2.setChecked(isChecked);
              }
          });

  mCheckBoxChoice1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
              @Override
              public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                  if (!isChecked)
                       mCheckBoxAll.setChecked(!isChecked);
              }
          });

  mCheckBoxChoice2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
              @Override
              public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                  if (!isChecked)
                       mCheckBoxAll.setChecked(!isChecked);
              }
          });
  ```

But this code doesn't work in case #2. All cases are unchecked in the same time...

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would put all your checkboxes that should change at once in a `RadioGroup`, and when `mCheckBoxAll` is checked iterate over RadioGroup and select / deselect them all

- case 1

  ```
  final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

  for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
      ((RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i)).setChecked(isChecked);
  }
  ```
- case 2 - you could call this method, to determine if one of the buttons is unchecked (call inside your 2 buttons onCheckedChanged). If it returns false, deselecte the main `RadioButton`.

  ```
  private boolean isButtonUnchecked() {

      for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
          RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
          if (!radioButton.isChecked()) {
              return false;
          }
      }

      return true;
  }
  ```

Comment: It's ok for that. The problem is when I want to unchecked mCheckBoxAll because one of other Checkbox has been unchecked too.

Comment: @anthony I have edited my answer, for you second case.

Answer (score 0):

When you checkbox2 is unchecked then you set the state of checkboxall to be unchecked, and there you call checkbox1 to be uncheck as well, here is your problem.

So if checkbox 1 and 2 are checked and then you unchecked checkbox2 it will affect checkbox1.

Edit:
You should identify the source of the unchecked in checkboxall, if it comes from one of the two checkbox or if it comes from the uncheck all.
The easiest solution is to declare a global variable in your activity/fragment which tells you if you comes from checkboxes 1 and 2.
And if your checkboxall listener uncheck 1 and 2 only if the value is true.
Don't forget to change its value when you are done to false.

Comment: I know that Galvan. So how can I do my final expected case ?

Answer (score 0):

Edited code:
modify your code to

```
mListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

             mCheckBoxChoice1.setChecked(isChecked);

        }
    };

mCheckBoxAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mListener);

mCheckBoxChoice1.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if (!isChecked){
                 mCheckBoxAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                 mCheckBoxAll.setChecked(!isChecked);
                 mCheckBoxAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mListener)
               } 
        }
    });

mCheckBoxChoice2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (!isChecked){
                 mCheckBoxAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                 mCheckBoxAll.setChecked(!isChecked);
                 mCheckBoxAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mListener)
               } 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code and it will work your scenario

```
 int   mCheckBoxAll_clicktimes=0;
    int  mCheckBoxChoice2_clicktimes=0;
    int mCheckBoxChoice1_clicktimes=0;

    mCheckBoxAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                mCheckBoxChoice1.setChecked(false);
                                mCheckBoxAll.setChecked(false);
                                mCheckBoxChoice2.setChecked(false);

                                mCheckBoxAll_clicktimes++;
                                mCheckBoxChoice2_clicktimes=0;
                                mCheckBoxChoice1_clicktimes=0;
                                if(mCheckBoxAll_clicktimes%2 !=0 || mCheckBoxAll_clicktimes==0){
//-----when mcheckbox all checked

                                    mCheckBoxAll.setChecked(true);
                                     mCheckBoxChoice1.setChecked(true);
                                 mCheckBoxChoice2.setChecked(true);                          

                                }else{
                                //===when mcheckboxall unchecked
                                          mCheckBoxChoice1.setChecked(false);
                                mCheckBoxAll.setChecked(false);
                                mCheckBoxChoice2.setChecked(false);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        mCheckBoxChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                mCheckBoxChoice1.setChecked(false);
                                mCheckBoxAll.setChecked(false);
                                mCheckBoxChoice2.setChecked(false);

                                mCheckBoxAll_clicktimes=0;
                                mCheckBoxChoice2_clicktimes=0;
                                mCheckBoxChoice1_clicktimes++;
                                if(mCheckBoxChoice1_clicktimes%2 !=0 || mCheckBoxChoice1_clicktimes==0){
                                //when mCheckBoxChoice1 checked
                                     mCheckBoxChoice1.setChecked(true);

                                }else{
                                //====when mCheckBoxChoice1 unchecked
                                          mCheckBoxChoice1.setChecked(false);
                                mCheckBoxAll.setChecked(false);
                                 }
                            }
                        });

                        mCheckBoxChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                mCheckBoxChoice1.setChecked(false);
                                mCheckBoxAll.setChecked(false);
                                mCheckBoxChoice2.setChecked(false);

                                mCheckBoxAll_clicktimes=0;
                                mCheckBoxChoice2_clicktimes++;
                                mCheckBoxChoice1_clicktimes=0;
                                if(mCheckBoxChoice2_clicktimes%2 !=0 || mCheckBoxChoice2_clicktimes==0){
                                //when mCheckBoxChoice2 checked
                                     mCheckBoxChoice2.setChecked(true);

                                }else{
                                //when mCheckBoxChoice2 unchecked
                                          mCheckBoxChoice2.setChecked(false);
                                mCheckBoxAll.setChecked(false);
                                 }
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: check edited answer... this will work your scenario for sure :)